# Linker errors in VS when using Windows API call in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, linker-errors

I am trying to get to grips with using Windows API functions, but making them work properly is proving difficult.

In VS2015, my C++ code currently produces linker errors whenever I call `MessageBox()` or anything similar:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;

int main()
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Stuff", L"Things", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return 0;
}
```

The errors I get are an unresolved token and an unresolved external symbol, with `MessageBoxW` appearing in the messages.

One of the error messages:
Error LNK2028 unresolved token (0A0004E9) "extern "C" int **stdcall MessageBoxW(struct HWND** *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?MessageBoxW@@$$J216YGHPAUHWND__@@PB_W1I@Z) referenced in function "extern "C" int **cdecl MessageBox(struct HWND** *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)" (?MessageBox@@$$J0YAHPAUHWND__@@PB_W1I@Z)

Comment: Your code is not C++. This is C++/CX or MC++.

Comment: But if this *was* a C++ project, ensure your linker has a reference to `User32.lib`.

Comment: You're trying to use the Windows C API? Not the .Net framework in C# or VB.Net? I think you're kinda mixed up. Follow these steps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx - or consider using c#, which it looks like you maybe saw an example of that and tried to use it in your c++ source.

Comment: What are the linking errors? Remove `Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");` and replace with `std::cout << "Hello world";`. Console::Writeline is C# not C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @mock_blatt it is entirely possible to write .net programs in C++ using the C++/CLI language

Comment: @JanarthK it is entirely possible to write .net programs in C++ using the C++/CLI language, which Visual Studio has templates for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally created a .net project, which implies you *aren't* going to be using the Windows API, at least not without some changes to your project. You need to create a Win32 project, not a .net project.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had made a Win32 Console Application but I may have accidentally chosen CLR. I made a new Win32 Console App in C++ just now, taking out the using statement and including std::cout. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to utilize WinAPI interfaces in the C++/CLI project, if your intention is to use only managed interfaces it is simpler to create a fully managed project (C#).

What you're missing here is a library inputs for linker (User32.lib as mentioned before in the comments).

See [Calling native Win32 code from .NET (C++/CLI and C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208890/calling-native-win32-code-from-net-c-cli-and-c) for the similar issue.